# Drag and Drop in datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am using two `Datagridview` in my code, i drag content from `Me.datagridview2` and drop it on `Me.datagridview1`.This process is successful. But as soon as i click the cell other than the dropped content cell, the dropped content disappears. Here's my code

```
 Private Sub DataGridView2_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.MouseDown
    Try
        If Me.DataGridView2.SelectedRows.Count = 0 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Me.DataGridView2.DoDragDrop(Me.DataGridView2.SelectedRows(0), DragDropEffects.All)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DragDrop
  Try
        Dim r As DataGridViewRow = e.Data.GetData(GetType(DataGridViewRow))
        If Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count = 0 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Dim i As Integer = Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Index
        Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = r.Cells(0).Value
        Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = r.Cells(1).Value
        Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value = r.Cells(2).Value
        Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value = r.Cells(3).Value

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_DragEnter(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DragEnter
    Try
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Have following doubts

1. why does the dropped content disappears.

2. whenever we begin edit on datagridview, a row in automatically added below. Why it doesn't gets added when i drop content in datagridview.?

Please help me.

Comment: I'm a little concerned on how you are adding that row with cells(num).value and not using a for loop in case you add a column in the future. There's also the fact that you're doing .SelectedRows(0).Index, what if you have multiple rows you selected and you want to drag/copy both?

Comment: dont you want to add a new row for the dropped data?  as is, it looks like you are replacing existing content

Comment: @sparkysword. actually i am dragging and dropping only one row at a time so therefore no loop required.

Comment: @Plutonix when i try adding that row it gives error that `when datagridview is databound, rows cannot be added programmatically`.

Comment: That's one of your problems there, then. Your datagridview has some data already bound/assigned to it.

Comment: So then what should i do @sparkysword, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, i just got an alternative to my own question. Here's it.

```
  Private Sub DataGridView1_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DragDrop
  Try
        Dim r As DataGridViewRow = e.Data.GetData(GetType(DataGridViewRow))
        If Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count = 0 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim i As Integer = Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Index
        dragseldet.Tables(0).Rows.Add("", r.Cells(0).Value, r.Cells(1).Value, r.Cells(2).Value, r.Cells(3).Value, 0, 0)
        dragseldet.AcceptChanges()
        'Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = r.Cells(0).Value
        'Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = r.Cells(1).Value
        'Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value = r.Cells(2).Value
        'Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value = r.Cells(3).Value

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Rather than copying the contents from `r` row to `Me.DataGridview.` all cells , i am directly adding `r` row to my datasource named `dragsaldet` . And that did the trick for me.